# Python sqlite3, saving instance of a class with an other instance as it's attribute?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, instance

I'm creating a game mod for Counter-Strike in python, and it's basically all done. The only thing left is to code a REAL database, and I don't have any experience on sqlite, so I need quite a lot of help.

I have a `Player` class with attribute `self.steamid`, which is unique for every Counter-Strike player (received from the game engine), and `self.entity`, which holds in an "Entity" for player, and `Entity`-class has lots and lots of more attributes, such as level, name and loads of methods. And Entity is a self-made Python class).

What would be the best way to implement a database, first of all, how can I save instances of Player with an other instance of Entity as it's attribute into a database, powerfully?

Also, I will need to get that users data every time he connects to the game server, (I have player_connect event), so how would I receive the data back?

All the tutorials I found only taught about saving strings or integers, but nothing about whole instances. Will I have to save every attribute on all instances (Entity instance has few more instances as it's attributes, and all of them have huge amounts of attributes...), or is there a faster, easier way?

Also, it's going to be a locally saved database, so I can't really use any other languages than sql.

Comment: You want to use [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ORM. Either you roll your own (which I never suggest), or you use one that exists already. Probably the two most popular in Python are sqlalchemy, and the ORM bundled with Django.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm gonna start learning SQLAlchemy when I get on hollidays. Damn I wished it could've been done with sqlite3, would have been so easy. But it can't be helped, thanks for your answer (and others too).

Answer (score 0):

SQL databses typically can hold only fundamental datatypes. You can use SQLAlchemy if you want to map your models so that their attributes are automatically mapped to SQL types - but it would require a lot of study and trial and error using SQLlite on your part.

I think you are not entirely correct when you say "it has to be SQL" - if you are running Python code, you can save whatver format you like.

However, Python allows you to serialize your instance Data to a string - which is persistable in a database.

So, you can create a varchar(65535) field in the SQL, along with an ID field (which could be the player ID number you mentioned, for example), and persist to it the value returned by:

```
import pickle

value = pickle.dumps(my_instance)
```

When retrieving the value you do the reverse:

```
my_instance = pickle.loads(value)
```

Comment: This will lead OP into writing their own ORM.

Comment: I don't know if it could be called "ORM" - but I would not say it should not. If he does write this functionality however, it still will work for his use case and be an order of magnitude simpler to use than existing ORMs.

Comment: It provides the same functionality as an ORM, and I have to say that I have never found maintaining my own code simpler than using a simple library.